# AWS Amazon Connect Lambda input request schema

Tags: aws-lambda

Where can I find a schema that *formally* outlines the Amazon Connect Lambda request format?   I don't see where Amazon has updated their supported Lambda event mapping documentation [1] or github hosted sdks

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html

Comment: I think the closest you'll get to a formal specification of the events submitted to AWS Lambda from Amazon Connect is the example event in the Amazon Connect documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

[This section of the admin guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html) demonstrates the input request as well as the response format.  The biggest key to remember is:

> The output returned from the function must be a flat object of key/value pairs, with values that include only alphanumeric, dash, and underscore characters. Nested and complex objects are not supported. The size of the returned data must be less than 32 Kb of UTF-8 data.

Hope this helps.